# How inefficient is update counter in cassandra compared to standard insert operations?

Tags: cassandra

I read Tyler Hobbs's guide to basic modelling in cassandra, here https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/basic-rules-of-cassandra-data-modeling and I notice the 1st footnote that said counter is exception to how cheap cassandra write is.

What's so inefficient about cassandra counter is ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check [this](https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/whats-new-in-cassandra-2-1-a-better-implementation-of-counters) and [this](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-6504)
to understand.

One statement regarding counter performance in above link:

> The new implementation does come with a price. Because we perform a
>   mutexed read-before-write now, latency for CL.ONE (or RF=1) to would
>   suffer with a naive implementation, particularly for many updates
>   contenting for few counter objects. To mitigate this, Cassandra 2.1
>   introduces a new form of cache, counter cache, to keep hot counter
>   values performant. Counter cache size and save period can be
>   configured in cassandra.yaml.

Comment: What about the implementation of counter in newer version of cassandra ? I somehow get it why It's inefficient thanks to you, yet are there improvement in later cassandra version?

Comment: you missed below section of the blog:   Future work
Cassandra 3.0 will finalise what was started in Cassandra 2.1. The primary task left is CASSANDRA–6506 - split counter context shards into separate cells, that will simplify counters implementation even further, and bring even more performance improvements for counters.

Comment: Well yeah I did miss that, and that's the answer that  I need, so yeah thanks !